# Why can this JpaRepository be used for an entity that it doesn't relate to?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

Spring Boot seems to be doing something behind the scenes that shouldn't work.

I'm moving a project to Spring Boot and was trying to get spring-boot-starter-data-jpa to work with the fewest changes to the code-base as I could get away with.

Somewhere in the code base, we marshal an xml or json document into an Entity using polymorphic dispatch, and send that entity straight to a database, without knowing exactly what type the entity was.

We have an interface Entity, from which many of our POJOs inherit:

```
public interface Entity {
  Long getId();
  void setId(Long id);
}
```

Example POJO:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table
public class Address implements Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  // fields, getters setters
}
```

Unfortunately, Spring CrudRepository and JpaRepository don't allow interfaces in the generics signature, so I created an AbstractEntity which inherits from Entity.

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="descriminatorColumn")
public class AbstractEntity implements Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I then created a repository for AbstractEntity:

```
public interface AbstractEntityRepository<T extends AbstractEntity, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

I was going to make my Entity POJOs inherit from AbstractEntity, but before I did I noticed that I don't need to.

The following code saves an address to the database:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.remsdaq.resque.officersubscription.*")
@EntityScan("com.remsdaq.resque.officersubscription.*")
public class OfficerSubscription implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(OfficerSubscription.class);

    @Autowired
    private AbstractEntityRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(OfficerSubscription.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Address address = new Address();
        repository.save(address);
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can my AbstractEntityRepository work, when AbstractEntity is not a superclass of Address?

If there's some reasonable reason why this works, and an expectation for this behavior not to change, it might not be too bad to leave it as it is, but without knowing how this is working, it's smelling too much for me to trust it.

Many thanks.

Comment: You autowire the `raw` repository, not the one using `<T extends AbstractEntity, ID>` I believe. So the compiler treats this as a raw repository which would accept any type (doesn't even need to be `Address`, you could probably add `new Object()`). I.e. if you autowired `List` rather than `List<Address>` you would be able to add anything to that list.

Comment: That makes sens, but I was previously `autowire`ing a raw repository, with Object in the generic signature, and Spring Boot would throw an exception stating that java.lang.Object is not a mapped type. What was causing this exception if it isn't thrown now?

Comment: If you autowire a specific type, spring will look for it. If you autowire a raw repo, it will look for a repo. There is no type information, so no checks will be done (haven't checked that yet, but pretty sure that's what it does). If you try to autowire a repo with a type, then it will check for repo + type and find none, therefore throwing an exception. Assumption: That would still work because internally it would look for annotations, regardless of type, and store that. Both of your entities are identical in their structure too, so they fit nicely into the same schema.